# how to allow root login via ttyS1 on CentOS?

Tags: centos7, pam

I want to be able to login to my servers via IPMI / serial console ttyS1.

Because IPMI is already asking for a password, the root password is printed to the console via `/etc/issue`.

Via Ubuntu Server 16.04 root login works flawlessly. In CentOS/vzlinux I cannot get it working.

I did the following:

```
echo ttyS1 >> /etc/securetty

cat >> /etc/security/access.conf << EOF
+ root : cron crond tty0 tty1 tty2 tty3 tty4 tty5 tty6 ttyS0 ttyS1
- root : ALL
EOF
```

Now the issue lies in the pam configuration. Getty will crash with pam errors:

[image: getty crash]

I think these are the offending lines of pam configuration:

[image: pam.d grep]

The `/etc/pam.d/*-ac` files are autogenerated, and should not be overwritten.

How should I fix this issue the 'correct' way?

How can I make the change only affecting login via ttyS1?

Answer (score 0):

My issue happened to be a systemd problem. For some reason, systemd didn't generate a "dev-ttyS1.device" unit, and therefore stopped getty (`Unit serial-getty@ttyS1.service is bound to inactive unit dev-ttyS1.device. Stopping, too`)

This fixed my getty issues:

```
srvfile="/etc/systemd/system/serial-getty@ttyS1.service"
echo -n "# This file has been created because of a bug in systemd\n\n" > $srvfile
cat /lib/systemd/system/serial-getty@.service >> $srvfile
sed -i 's/dev-%i\.device //g' $srvfile
sed -i 's/dev-%i\.device//g' $srvfile
```

Comment: Strange, works for me, I don't need to do this. Do you have a bug link?

Comment: No, wasn't sure where to report it and how to reproduce it exactly. Maybe it has been fixed already

Comment: It's also possible that I triggered this by doing some other weird stuff

Comment: This isn't a bug, it's intentional. Systemd only creates a serial getty unit by default for the system serial console, if one is defined.

Answer (score 0):

Systemd only creates a serial getty unit by default for the system serial console, if one is defined. This is generally done with `console=` on the kernel command line.

Because you're trying to use a serial tty that isn't the defined console, [you have to enable getty yourself](http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/serial-console.html). This is trivially easy, as this is an [instantiated](http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/instances.html) unit:

```
systemctl enable serial-getty@ttyS1.service
systemctl start serial-getty@ttyS1.service
```

You don't need to hack at or copy any service files.